# How do I determine if an indexed mode SDL_Surface has transparency or not?

Tags: c++, transparency, sdl, indexed-image

I've got code I've been working with to load and convert `SDL_Surface`s to OpenGL textures, however I've realized that they only work with RGB(A) surfaces. I need to extend the support onto indexed mode images (with or without transparency).

Initially, I was looking into `::SDL_SetColorKey()`, however it seems to only work with SDL blits. I've read up on `SDL_Surface`, `SDL_PixelFormat` and `SDL_Color`, and then begun to sketch up the following (//# is pseudocode):

```
SDL_Surface *pSurf(::IMG_Load(image));
::SDL_LockSurface(pSurf);

Uint32 bytesPerPixel(pSurf->format->bytesPerPixel);
GLenum pixelFormat;

Uint8  *pixelData(pSurf->pixels);
bool   allocated(false); // pixelData isn't allocated

if(pSurf->format->palette != 0) // indexed mode image
{
  //# Determine transparency. // HOW?
  //# bytesPerPixel = 3 or 4 depending on transparency being present;
  //# pixelFormat = GL_RGB or GL_RGBA depending on bytesPerPixel;

  Uint32 blockSize(pSurf->w * pSurf->h * bytesPerPixel);
  pixelData = new Uint8[blockSize];
  allocated = true;

  //# traverse pSurf->pixels, look up pSurf->format->palette references and copy
  // colors into pixelData;
}
else
{
  //# Determine pixelFormat based on bytesPerPixel and pSurf->format->Rmask
  // (GL_RGB(A) or GL_BGR(A)).
}

//# Pass bytesPerPixel, pixelFormat and pixelData to OpenGL (generate texture,
// set texture parameters, glTexImage2D etc).

if(allocated)
{
  delete[] pixelData;
  pixelData = 0;
}

::SDL_UnlockSurface(pSurf);
::SDL_FreeSurface(pSurf);
```

So, the question is: how can I determine if the indexed mode image I'm passing to this routine has transparency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way it's done for indexed mode is either to have a full 32-bit RGBA palette, so you have 8 bits of alpha per indexed color slot. Or, you can just define a certain (range of) palette index as being transparent.

OpenGL supports the latter, through the `GL_PIXEL_MAP_I_TO_A` table accessed through `glPixelMap()`. See `glPixelTransfer()` for a description of the translation logic.

Comment: is there any way to deduce the transparency directly from the SDL_Surface structure that is being created from the image file (.gif, .ico)? (such as background color, colorkey, n'th color in the palette...?)